# Show that $R(\partial_i,\partial_j)h_{kp}=0$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

In picture below, I am not sure why $R(\partial_i,\partial_j)h_{kp}=0$.
I think it is because we can consider $h_{kp}$ as a function. Am I right ?

The picture below is from 57th page of this [paper](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/%7Eandrews/book.pdf).

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Can you also link the reference?

Comment: @JohnMa  Sorry , I miss it .I have added it .

Comment: Yes, you are right, in that formula $h_{kl}$ is really a function so the second derivative commutes.

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks.